# how to get vscode to show local branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I created a branch from the command line and added some shell scripts to my tree and deleted one file.
I did a `git add -A`, `git commit` and pushed the changes to origin.
I did not merge the changes yet.

When I open the folder in VSCode it opens to branch `master` and does not show my changes.

- I did a `git status` from a shell window, and it shows the branch as active.
- I did a `git status` from the VSCode terminal window, and it shows `master` as the active branch.

And:

- When I do a `git branch` from a shell window I see both `master` and my branch, with my branch with the asterisk indicating it is active.
- When I do a branch on the VSCode terminal, it only shows me `master`.

When I select the branch indicator in the lower left hand corner of VSCode, it only shows me `master` and merged branches in `origin`.
It does not show my new local branch.

How do I work on the local branch in VSCode?
I am running VSCode1.59 insiders on RedHat 7.7.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're in the same folder? Try creating a new branch from the VSCode terminal and check if you can see it in the regular shell window.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact a Rhel 7.7 is bound to have a Git positively ancient (like 1.8, instead of the current 2.32), it should display the same in command-line and VSCode.

Try and reopen VSCode from the root folder of your local repository.

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
code .
```

(You can also add [GitLens as a VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), to get more information)

---

The [OP Jeff Gaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828259/jeff-gaer) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850577/how-to-get-vscode-to-show-local-branches#comment121705815_68855977):

> I had done and open folder to switch to the local repository from another directory. Maybe that was it.
>
> I did '`code .`' and now see the local branch.
> I can even switch repositories doing an open folder and see the current local branch in each repository.
>
> So its definitely working now. But I am not sure what fixed it.

Comment: I had done and open folder to switch to the local repository from another directory. Maybe that was it. I did 'code .' and now see the local branch. I can even switch repositories doing an open folder and see the current local branch in each repository. So its definitely working now. But I am not sure what fixed it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @JeffGaer Great! Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.